# Is Win32 window class registration threadsafe?

Tags: c++, class, winapi, thread-safety, mutex

I am currently struggeling about thread-safe window creation with the Win32 API. All my previous applications used a single HWND in a static context. Now i want to have multiple windows wrapped up in a custom window class. In the constructor, a window counter is checked. If it is 0, the static method `register_window_class` should be called once, which registers a WNDCLASSEX structure to a static HINSTANCE as usual.

```
static void register_window_class();
```

The same principle applies to window creation, destruction and unregistering of the window class.

Now I am not sure if those calls are thread-safe or not. Should I do this

```
Window::Window()
{
  if(_WindowCounter == 0)
  {
    register_window_class();
  }
}
```

or this

```
std::mutex _Mutex;   // one mutex per window object    

Window::Window()
{
  _Mutex.lock();

  if(_WindowCounter == 0)
  {
    register_window_class();
  }

  _Mutex.unlock();
}
```

or am I completely wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether window registration in Windows API is thread-safe, since you plan to arrange for it to only be called once. You need to be concerned about your code, where you attempt to ensure that it is in fact only called once. Where and how is `_WindowCounter` updated?

Comment: "one mutex per window object" won't help in any way in maintaining a counter shared by multiple objects.

Comment: *"thread-safe window creation"* - Window creation is thread safe. It is also [technically safe](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=4683) to spread your UI across multiple threads. Though, if you have to ask, you're best adviced to not even think about creating a multi-threaded UI.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Actually it does matter if it is thread-safe, because OP allows this call to be made from any thread, although it prevents it from overlapping a call to register the same window classname in another thread, there's no attempt to prevent simultaneously registering a different window class (perhaps inside a library function) in another thread.  Because of this difficulty of having the application programmer responsible for synchronizing calls from different libraries in different threads, of course the OS does the synchronization.

Comment: *You tell us.* If the first thread is still busy doing register_window_class and the second thread just creates the window with the window class that hasn't been registered yet, what happens?

Comment: The sequence of registering the window class and creating the windows is not quite the point. I was not sure if static class variables, like my HINSTANCE, should be protected by a mutex lock.

Comment: _"...static class variables, like my HINSTANCE..."_: none of this is in the posted code.  How are we supposed to help (answer) if you post different/irrelevant code.

Comment: You assign to the HINSTANCE variable in the main thread before you do anything else. Why would there ever be an issue with threading on that variable?

Comment: Just register your window classes when your program starts up. Why complicate things like this?